# Listing of files from directory and sub-directories

Tags: list, file, directory

I am using the following code. But it fails to deliver the output in the textbox t1.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Dim fp As String

Private Sub b1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b1.Click
    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        fp = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        t2.Text = fp
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub b2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b2.Click
    Dim filelist As String() = Directory.GetFiles(fp, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For Each filename As String In filelist
        t1.AppendText(filename)
    Next

End Sub
```

I am unable to trace where lies the mistake. Help is needed
Thanks

Comment: It might sound ridiculous but I believe my code is perfect then why output is not there as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the silly thing was to insert the type of files i.e., "*.*" in GetFiles.